# How can I fix the error 'Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthenticationManager' type found' in Spring Security implementation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
package com.calorie.calorie.tracker.service;
/*
* Implementation of SecurityService interface
* */

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    public String findLoggedInUsername() {
        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
        if(userDetails instanceof UserDetails){
            return ((UserDetails)userDetails).getUsername();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void autoLogin(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        if(authenticationToken.isAuthenticated()){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

            logger.debug(String.format("Successfully %s auto logged in", username));
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, an `error` occurs at line 22, namely "private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;", where `authenticationManager` is defined as an error. What can I do or what information can I provide to solve this problem? Extremely grateful in advance.

Comment: please report errore message